# How to pass a variable from HTML to Java?

Tags: java, html

I want to pass a variable from HTML to Java. For this, I wrote the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>


    <title>How to create a typewriter or typing effect with jQuery</title>
    <div id="example1">fsdfsdfojsdlk sdfj lskdhfk sdf </div>
    <style>
        body{

    background: transparent;

    color: #ec5a62;

        }

        #container{
            font-size: 7em;
        }  

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <!-- 
        We use Google's CDN to serve the jQuery js libs. 
        To speed up the page load we put these scripts at the bottom of the page 
    -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        //define text
 var text = ("document.getElementById("example1")");

        //text is split up to letters
        $.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter){

            //we add 100*i ms delay to each letter 
            setTimeout(function(){

                //we add the letter to the container
                $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);

            }, 30*i);
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working. How can I achieve this?

Please do help me.

I'm using **var text =("document.getElementById("example1")");**

But its not working.

Comment: Learning to work with jsp/jsf and servlets would come in handy here.

Comment: It is not really clear what you ask: if your code, the html document, is rendered inside a web browser, then the code is executed on the client side. There is no connection to any java code which can only be located on the server side and your code makes no attempt to send anything...

Comment: To pass a variable from HTML-page to Java servlet, you need to send ajax-request. 
Maybe you want to pass variable to Javascript code?
Javascript not equal Java!

Answer (score 1):

to get value use var x=document.getElementById("example1").value;

your code should be like this:

```
var text=document.getElementById("example1").value;
 //text is split up to letters
    $.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter){

        //we add 100*i ms delay to each letter 
        setTimeout(function(){

            //we add the letter to the container
            $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);

        }, 30*i);
    });
```